# Example of non-measurable stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> A stochastic process $X(t, \omega)$ is said measurable if, as a function, $X:T \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it is  $\left< \mathcal{T}\times\mathcal{F, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})}\right>$-measurable.

From my reading, as an example of non-measurable stochastic process, I've got $X(t, \omega)=f(t)$ for an $f(t)$ non measurable. I've found it unsatisfactory, indeed for the most common measurable spaces, namely $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, we have that such function doesn't exist or relies on the axiom of choice.

Is there a more natural example of non-measurable stochastic process? Thank you in advance.